# How to connect to multiple hosts through SSH, with the "same ip", with "Better Terminal Emulator Pro"?

Tags: applications, networking, ssh, terminal

I'm trying to set up SSH connections to my home network. The application I'm using is Better Terminal Emulator Pro. But it only allows me to connect to one host with the same IP address(the external IP), it doesn't understand that it's a different port.

I created 3 shortcuts for the SHH sessions, but only one works.

The network is a LAN behind a router. I need to connect to multiple hosts on this network.

I can do this with another terminal, don't remember which one. But I like Better Terminal Emulator Pro so, any ideas?

Comment: I saw your flag requesting migration -- it seems to me that this site is the best place to ask, or at least it's certainly on-topic here, and shouldn't be closed.  However, if you feel it would be on-topic for SU as well then you can feel free to ask there as well.  Making a note of the reason for the cross-post should prevent any negative reception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally most of the SSH clients I have used work fine (e.g. JuiceSSH / SSH droid) so I would really recommend changing.

If you are really determined to do this then you could use a separate ssh program in a terminal (not sure if this will work) or you could try setting up multiple IP addresses on the linux laptop.

Let's say you have an IP address like 192.168.0.7/24

Then (if you own the network or have permission to use the other addresses) you could login as root and do

```
ip address add 192.168.0.8/24 dev eth0
```

then you will be able to login to the same laptop on a different address.  You'll find plenty of tutorials on the web for setting up IP addresses on Linux so I won't go into the full details.

I should probably also mention solutions such as the linux programs screen and dtach which allow you to have multiple shell sessions on one terminal.  Those are probably in many ways better for you.